# Laravel 5.3 - Failed login attempt redirect

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5.3

In my application I'm using the default authentication with Laravel 5.3. I have two places where a user can log in and I'm wanting to, in the event of a failed login, redirect to only one of those two places. In other words, whatever view a user logs in through, if they submit invalid credentials, they will always be redirected back to one specific view instead of whatever view they submitted the form from. In Laravel 5.1 it looks like this could be achieved by including the [$loginPath](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating) variable in the login controller. In [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) they seem to have taken that option out of the documentation so I'm not sure how to approach this anymore.

Any thoughts and/or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit: I misunderstood your original question. This is updated.**

If you need to customize this, you can do something like:

Open `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` (as [per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#introduction), this would have been generated by the `php artian make:auth` command thay I'm assuming you used) and add this:

```
/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->to('/the_redirect_location')
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}
```

This will overwrite the same method that's contained in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait that `LoginController` uses. The `redirect()->to('/the_redirect_location')` is the part I've changed. Originally, it's: `redirect()->back()`.

If you choose to use this method, be sure to add this at the top of `LoginController`:

```
use Lang;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking for a solution for Laravel version `5.7`. I was able to make this work by adding the following `sendFailedLoginResponse` method to `LoginController`

```
/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse()
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ])
    ->redirectTo("/the_redirect_location");
}
```

And don't forget the following imports:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

*Note*: The difference between this method and the one it overrides from  `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticateUsers` is the line `->redirectTo(" 
/the_redirect_location");`

Where `/the_redirect_location` is the URL you want to redirect to when authentication fails.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file *Authenticate.php* and change the method `redirectTo()` like this for each route you want to redirect from that has failed.

```
protected function redirectTo($request) {
  if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
    if ($request->path() == "user/dashboard"){
      return route('user.login.form');
    } else {
      return route('HOME');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem while using Laravel 8 with Fortify authentication, and found my way to this page after searching "laravel failed login redirects to homepage".

If you are having a problem where users are being redirected to the homepage rather than seeing an error message when they log in incorrectly, the solution is to change your Referrer-Policy from "strict-origin" to "same-origin".  The issue is documented here:
https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/laravel-redirects-break-when-using-origin-referrer-policy
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-fortify-redirect-after-fail-login

To resolve the issue, your .htaccess should include something like this:

```
Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
```